# How to generate web API docs from python docstrings

Tags: python-sphinx

I have a Django website and I created a REST api.  In the view functions I have documentation on the REST urls and I want to generate API docs for the REST urls.  The view functions look like this:

```
def genres(request):
    """
    Url: /api/genres/
    Parameters: None
    Returns: list of genres { { "id":1, "name":"action" }, {...} }
    """
    pass
```

But when I run sphinx on myproject.api.views I get html docs for calling the api in python.  Is there a way to configure sphinx to document it like a REST api?

Or am I better off writing a script to generate my docs from the docstrings myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [sphinxcontrib-httpdomain](http://packages.python.org/sphinxcontrib-httpdomain/)

You can use autodoc in order to use the docstrings and the httpdomain extension in order to use .. http:get:: /users/ style directives. This solution has a problem, it will also show the functions' signatures. In order to get around the problem, I tinkered a bit with the Sphinx source code, making a copy of the original autodoc extension that wouldn't add the signatures to the final documentation.

The files can be found on https://gist.github.com/4589457

Instructions:

1. Replace **application.py** on sphinx path with the one on the [gist](https://gist.github.com/4589457) (the path on my system is /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.1.3-py2.7.egg/sphinx/)
2. Add **simpleautodoc.py** on the ext folder
3. Add the **httpdomain** extension on conf.py in order to use .. http:get:: /users/ style directives
4. Use simpleautodoc as you would use autodoc using the prefix **autosimple** instead of auto (eg autosimplemodule instead of automodule autosimpleclass instead of autoclass etc)
5. The **example.py** file shows a sample of how I format the docstrings

Comment: Looks like we'd have to keep the documentation separate from the code to use sphinxcontrib-httpdomain.  Is there a way to have it use the docstrings from the view functions?

Comment: The provided link is down.